# Dialog close event in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, dialog, event-handling

I am using jquery mobile and a dialog to display some multiple select boxes. Some of the content is dynamically created with Ajax based on the selections. I would like to make the Ajax call when the dialog is closed (through the regular x button). The main parts of the html look as follows:

```
    <a href="#queryPage" data-rel="dialog"  data-transition="slidedown"  >Filter Results</a>
    <div data-role="page" id="queryPage" data-theme="a">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="a">
    <h1>Select Filters</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
    <form action="" method="get" id="filterForm">
    <fieldset id ="filterFields"></fieldset>
    </form>
    </div>
    </div>
```

I am currently making the call by running the code on page hide as follows:
        `$('#queryPage').live('pagehide', function(event) {
        //code for ajax call
        });`

However, I would like to make the call when the dialog closes because some of the select lists are large and they create a new page that hides the queryPage even though the dialog has not been closed. I have tried:

```
    $('#queryPage').bind('dialogclose', function(event) {
         alert('closed');
     });
```

and also tried

```
    $('#queryPage').dialog({close:function(event, ui){
        alert("closed");
    }});
```

These I have put in a function called on page load but the alert is not shown when the dialog is closed. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 12):

There are no specific events for dialogs as they are simply pages that are displayed as a dialog. Try the `pagehide` event.

```
$("#MyDialog").bind("pagehide",function(){
  alert("Dialog closed");
});
```

Also, the first line of your sample code has a link that is outside of a `<div data-role="page">` which should not be done.

Comment: Sorry, I left the rest of the page html code out for that first line as I didnt think it was necessary for the question. Like I said, I am currently using 'pagehide' but I am looking for better or just other ways to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Pagehide can be delegated as such:

```
$(document).delegate("#MyDialog", "pagehide", function() {
  alert("Dialog closed");
});
```

and you will also have access to the screen elements of the calling page.

Answer (score 1):

Andleer shared the appropriate event for closing the dialog using jquery. however, we can also code in this way.

```
    $(document).on("pagehide","#Dialog",function(){
        console.log('Dialog has closed.');
    });
```